# Need to update a column in SQL with WHERE using comma separated values from textbox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Just to let you guys know I'm not a programmer @ all but I can manage to get code to work sometimes but I'm stumped now. I have a c# web-based project that I finally figured out how to pass comma-separated values from a single textbox to return a result in Datagrid when I click search. The code looks like this:

```
    {
String str = "select row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [sequenceid]) #,[JobNumber],[Item],Quantity,Bay,Trailer,Sequenceid, Produced from vwcabsandcountersbyjob ";

String str1 = "select SUM([Quantity])AS [Items Remaining to Be Loaded] from vwcabsandcountersbyjob";
        
        //CODE THAT ALLOWS MULTIPLE ORDER NUMBERS TO BE ENTERED IN A SINGLE TEXTBOX
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            List<string> search = new List<string>();
            char[] characters = { ',', '\n' };
            string[] ids = TextBox1.Text.Trim().Split(characters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                search.Add(ids[i].Trim());
            }

            str += " WHERE (jobnumber IN ('"  + string.Join("','", search.ToArray()) +  "') and loaded is null) ORDER BY ITEM DESC";
        }

        //CODE THAT ALLOWS MULTIPLE ORDER NUMBERS TO BE ENTERED IN A SINGLE TEXTBOX
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            List<string> search = new List<string>();
            char[] characters = { ',', '\n' };
            string[] ids = TextBox1.Text.Trim().Split(characters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                search.Add(ids[i].Trim());
            }

            str1 += " WHERE (jobnumber IN ('" + string.Join("','", search.ToArray()) + "') and loaded is null) ";
        }



        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
        SqlCommand xp1 = new SqlCommand(str1, vid);


        //xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        xp1.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        vid.Open();
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "[jobnumber]");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        vid.Close();

        vid.Open();
        xp1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da1.SelectCommand = xp1;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds1, "[jobnumber]");
        GridView2.DataSource = ds1;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        vid.Close();

    }
```

Now i have a second button that I want to update a field when they press "mark complete".  It works fine with a single entry and here is the code:

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vid.Open();

        
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Update [Job_Master] SET [Completed] = GETDATE() WHERE [job number] =@search", vid);
        SqlCommand xp3 = new SqlCommand("Update [Countertops] SET [Completed] = GETDATE() WHERE [jobnumber] =@search", vid);



        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        xp3.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        xp3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        vid.Close();

        string message = "This job has been marked complete!";
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "')};";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);

    }
```

The problem is it only works for one value.  I've tried a million different things but nothing works mainly because I don't know what I'm doing.  This is the closest I've come (i added a 3rd button because i didn't want to break button 2 that works for single value):

```
   Protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str3 = "Update [Job_Master] SET [Completed] = GETDATE()";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            List<string> search = new List<string>();
            char[] characters = { ',', '\n' };
            string[] ids = TextBox1.Text.Trim().Split(characters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                search.Add(ids[i].Trim());
            }

            str3 += " WHERE [job number] IN ('" + string.Join("','", search.ToArray()) + "')";
        }

        SqlCommand xp4 = new SqlCommand(str3, vid);


        vid.Open();

        xp4.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        

        xp4.ExecuteNonQuery();
      
        vid.Close();

        string message = "This job has been marked complete!";
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "')};";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);

    }
```

and it doesn't work. It only updates when I have a single entry. My question is how do use those same values from that textbox work in an update statement? I hope I'm being clear but will try my best to answer any questions but please remember my vocabulary is very limited when it comes to programming. Thanks!

Comment: Don't build SQL queries through string concatenation as this leaves your application open to SQL injection. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: @DanielMann It's annoying there isn't a good way to parameterize an array in C#. It's essentially better to ensure each element in array is numeric in cases like this

Comment: I think you pretty much figured it out. You just need to open your db connection BEFORE creating the command.

Comment: Did you get any error message on that code? If yes, what is it?

Comment: I moved vid.Open(); directly under-protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) but it still doesn't update anything when I run it.

Comment: Is it _[job number]_ or is _[jobnumber]_?

Comment: [job number] for this field.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Table Valued Parameter is usually the best way of passing an array

Comment: @Charlieface yes. It's available for Transact-SQL but not the engines I use most.

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise if you just divide your code into smaller parts, group them by their role and responsibility. This would make things much easier to maintain and also to work with.

if you see repetitive code, then it's a flag of moving it to a separate method.

A few notes that I've found in your code :

- you should use `using` clause when possible, like using it with `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataAdapter`.
- Multiple unneeded `SqlCommand` are used.
- Providing `SqlParamter` while the query doesn't have any parameter.
- using string concatenation is not optimal, instead use `StringBuilder`.
- Your business logic should have its own methods or classes, and can be recalled inside any event.
- `Split` returns `Array`, so no need to convert `Array` to another `Array`.
- Always, each portion of the code, should be scoped to that portion role only. For instance, `OnClick` event, should handle the click event only, and not handling the update records. The update part should be declared and handled outside the event, and you only recall it from inside the event.

I have updated the code, which would give you a better view on the above notes:

```
protected void SearchButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //CODE THAT ALLOWS MULTIPLE ORDER NUMBERS TO BE ENTERED IN A SINGLE TEXTBOX
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
    {
        SearchAndBind(TextBox1.Text);
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textValue = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
    
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textValue))
    {
        UpdateRecords("UPDATE [Job_Master] SET [Completed] = GETDATE() WHERE [job number] = @search", "@search", textValue);    
        
        UpdateRecords("UPDATE [Countertops] SET [Completed] = GETDATE() WHERE [jobnumber] = @search", "@search", textValue);    
                
        CompletedJobNotification();
    }

}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inClause = GetInClause(TextBox1.Text); 

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inClause))
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("Update [Job_Master] SET [Completed] = GETDATE()");
        
        query.Append(" WHERE [job number] ").Append(inClause);
        
        UpdateRecords(query.ToString());
        
        CompletedJobNotification();
    }
}


private void PopulateData(string query, string srcTable, GridView gridView)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
        {
            adapter.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, srcTable);
            gridView.DataSource = ds;
            gridView.DataBind();
        }
        
    }
}

private string GetInClause(string text)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    {
        char[] characters = { ',', '\n' };
        var ids = text.Trim().Split(characters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return "IN ('"  + string.Join("','", ids) +  "')";
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

private void SearchAndBind(string search)
{
    //CODE THAT ALLOWS MULTIPLE ORDER NUMBERS TO BE ENTERED IN A SINGLE TEXTBOX
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
    {
        string inClause = GetInClause(search); 
        
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inClause))
        {
            var searchWhere = $" WHERE jobnumber loaded IS NULL AND {inClause} ";   

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [sequenceid]) #,[JobNumber],[Item],Quantity,Bay,Trailer,Sequenceid, Produced FROM vwcabsandcountersbyjob");

            StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder("SELECT SUM([Quantity]) AS [Items Remaining to Be Loaded] FROM vwcabsandcountersbyjob");
            
            str.Append(searchWhere).Append(" ORDER BY ITEM DESC ");

            str1.Append(searchWhere);
            
            PopulateData(str.ToString(), "[jobnumber]", GridView1);
            
            PopulateData(str1.ToString(), "[jobnumber]", GridView2);            
        }       
    }   
}

    
private void UpdateRecords(string query, string parameterName = null,string parameterValue = null)  
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterValue))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, parameterValue);     
        }
            
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
    }
}


private void ShowJavaScriptAlert(string message)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inClause))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", $" window.onload = function(){{ alert('{message}')}}; ", true);
    }   
}

private void CompletedJobNotification()
{
    ShowJavaScriptAlert("This job has been marked complete!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first up, we are writing too much code here.

Next up, we can MOST certainly have a list of parameters, and they can be optional, and we NEVER concatenate user input into the SQL string - we don't have to.

Now, I don't have the users data, lets do this:

I can type in a city, or several. I will display some hotels, and then ONE button to confirm the hotels and update the database with the confirm date.

(the same as what you are doing).

Ok, so a text box, and a button. Like this:

```
    Search: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPromptCity" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="336px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search City" Style="margin-left:20px" />
```

So, you can type in one city, or several (with a , in between). Same as what you need/are doing.

Ok, so when you type in and hit search, we send the results to a grid view.

So, we have this code for the button:

```
    DataTable rstHotels = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
            rstHotels = (DataTable)ViewState["rstHotels"];
    }

    protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] strChoices;
        strChoices = txtPromptCity.Text.Split(',');

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            string strSQL = "";
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string strCity in strChoices)
            {
                if (strSQL != "")
                    strSQL += ",";
                i += 1;
                strSQL += "@" + i;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strCity;
            }

            cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE City IN (" + strSQL + ")";

            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            rstHotels.Rows.Clear();
            rstHotels.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            ViewState["rstHotels"] = rstHotels;
            GridView1.DataSource = rstHotels;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

note how I keep/have the data table - I persist it at the class level.

So, our output is now this

[image]

Ok, so we now have the parameter issue working.

Now, all you have to do is check box the ones to approve, and then send the data back to the table - along with the approved visit date.

That code NOW becomes dead simple.

We can use this:

```
    protected void cmdConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkVisit = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkVisit");

            if (chkVisit.Checked)
                // update Visit date in table
                rstHotels.Rows[gvRow.RowIndex]["VistDate"] = DateTime.Today;

            // now send table changes back to database.

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels where ID = 0", 
             new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daUpate = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstHotels);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, note how we send the grid choices back to the table, and then send the table back to the database. This makes the whole process easy, and VERY much less code.

And I would probably add a 2-3 lines more code in the Row bound event, and set the checkbox if the row has a date already. And we could I suppose even check if we un-check the checkbox, and again null out the date column row.

All of these are VERY dead easy with the above approach.

So, persisting the table as per above - makes this REALLY easy. And note the data Keys setting - we can use/get/grab the primary key of each row and not have to display it - but this example does not see to need this ability anyway.

The markup I used for above is this:

```
    Search: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPromptCity" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="336px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search City" Style="margin-left:20px" OnClick="cmdSearch_Click" />

    <div style="width:45%;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"            />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VistDate" HeaderText="Visit Date"  DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"  />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Confirm Visit"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkVisit" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm Vists" Width="143px" CssClass="btn-info" OnClick="cmdConfirm_Click" />
        <br />

    </div>
```

Comment: This looks nice too Albert but one notable difference is that as they scan items the grid view will slowly decrease until there is nothing left in the grid. It will be @ this point they will mark complete (i know you didn't have any user data).

Comment: We could have the check box do a post back - not have that button to process all rows. The code would still be much the same - just that clicking a check box, or row click or button on a row click would still be the same. So this can be per row click or check box Just use sender.parent.parent to get the grid row. - it would be even less code then I posted. .  It was never clear if we want each row, or a one shot database update as above shows. The one shot idea does give rise to a un-do ability, but the posted code would in fact even be shorter if we are to process per row on user actions

Comment: The optional processing for 1, or 10 parameters I have works. That could EASY be a update statement - note how I use SELECT * from mytable where ID in (@1, @2, @3 etc.). So I allow as many parameters as there was items typed into the text box, and this idea will work just fine for a update command as opposed to me having used a select command. The MANY posts here for some strange reason seem to forget that the adding of parameters in a loop, and building of the SQL can both be done as I have posted here. This simple idea is thus the Rosetta stone to your all your problems.

Comment: I am going to try and incorporate some of this because i know mine is very very sloppy. Thanks for taking the time to post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the help from everyone. The actual was that my aspx code was pointing to OnClick="Button2_Click" and not OnClick="Button3_Click". Once i fixed that and put in the original code it worked. Having said that you guys have pointed out some great points that i'm going to try and fix. Again, i'm not a programmer and sure appreciate you guys helping. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, good job getting as far as you did. I think the only thing left is just a simple mistake. I'll provide this which removes a little of the code you don't need

```
Protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str3 = "Update [Job_Master] SET [Completed] = GETDATE()";

// ** This is a little dangerous. If the TextBox is EMPTY, you will be
// ** Updating ALL rows in the table. I assume that is not what you want.
// ** You should return an error if text box is empty.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            char[] characters = { ',', '\n' };
            char[] invalid = { ',',';',' ','\'','"','\\','\t' };
            string[] ids = TextBox1.Text.Trim().Split(characters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            //
            // ** You don't really need to copy into a list.
            // ** If you want to trim each entry, you can just
            // ** replace in the original array.
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                ids[i] = ids[i].Trim();
                // ** Add a check here to make sure id is safe
                // ** to prevent SQL injection.
                if (ids[i].IndexOfAny( invalid ) != -1)
                {
                     return; // should give error, probably.
                }
            }

// *** figure out if it is job_number or jobnumber or (unlikely) job number
            str3 += " WHERE [job_number] IN ('" + string.Join("','", ids) + "')";
        }
        else {
            return; // empty string. Should give error.
        }

        // ** OPEN FIRST
        vid.Open();
        SqlCommand xp4 = new SqlCommand(str3, vid);


        // ** @search not needed 
        // xp4.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        

        xp4.ExecuteNonQuery();
      
        vid.Close();

        string message = "This job has been marked complete!";
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "')};";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);

    }
```

Now, if the IDs are not supposed to be numeric, you have a little more difficulty preventing SQL injection. You'd want to create a parameter for each one (@1, @2, @3, etc...) and add each as a parameter.

Or, of course, you could run a separate SQL statement for each ID. Not super efficient but probably fast enough.

Comment: Thanks Garr but it still doesn't update the completed field when i run it. It doesn't error out but it doesn't update either.

Comment: @diglife did you figure out "job number" vs "jobnumber"?

Comment: Yes, it should be [job number]. I'm getting away with using [jobnumber] on the select statement only because it's pulling from a view in SQL but for this update it has to be  [job number].

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. The id's will look like this: E3439,R39384,T39493 (these are just examples illustrating mix of letter followed by numbers).  It also gives me an error : CS1525: Invalid expression term 'long' for this line if (!Int64.TryParse(ids[i], out long id)) but even if I comment that line out it still appears to run but doesn't update anything.

Comment: Ok, you can't do the `TryParse` technique if you have letters in the IDs. Can you get a copy of the SQL string it creates and show us the error you get? Can you execute the command in the studio directly?

Comment: Sadly, I'm not sure how to copy the SQL string it creates.  It's weird because It doesn't generate an error it just doesn't update that field in SQL when I run it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I get no errors only a warning that reads : unreachable code detected for this line: for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)

Comment: Ok so i found why it ran with no errors...on the aspx page i copied button 2 but didn't change it to button 3.  Now it's actually calling on button3_click and when I run it and i don't get any errors but nothing happens either. I don't even get the job marked complete message i was getting before.

Comment: sounds like it is now bailing out at one of the "return" statements. You should add some error response code so you can tell what happened.  It's probably on the `TryParse` code since the IDs are not numeric. I'll remove that in the answer